# Find the rule to be part of the set

Tags: word

I'll give you a set of words:

> { Achieve, Dog, Cool, Report, Take }

Now if I tell you that `Pay` can also be in this set, can you find the rule allowing a word to be part of this set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All words in the set can be

> prefixed with 'under': [underachieve](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underachieve), [undercool](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undercool), [underdog](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underdog), [underpay](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underpay), [underreport](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underreport), [undertake](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undertake).

As requested by the OP: how did I find it?

> Being a 'word' riddle, I tried to find words to put before and after your set of words. I stumbled upon 'under' rather quickly, but that might be a coincidence.

Comment: So fast. Can I ask you how did you find so quickly? I'm not an english speaker so maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker either ... I have put my train of thoughts into the spoiler in the answer :)

Comment: Alright, good to know. Good job anyway :)